# Does the global timer matter?

Tags: dead-cells

I know that there are time-locked doors in Dead Cells (get there fast enough and they are unlocked). However, is there anything else that the global timer affects? If I want to take my time and peruse each level, am I ultimately penalized for dawdling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing besides the doors that operate off the timer.

The only other 'penalty' for not rushing would be possibly taking more damage, from either fighting more enemies, or having to go through more traps.  This may result in flask use (More of a penalty with additional boss cells).

Comment: So does damage scale with time somehow? I'm not sure I understand how I would take more damage by taking my time.

Comment: Sorry, no, the damage does not increase.  If you are very careful, you won't take damage.  My experience has been more that I'll slip up and take damage, either from traps or just fighting more enemies.

Comment: @mmatthews On the other hand, it also offers the opportunity to find some free healing, so you could end up with more HP.